# Python, VTK and GIL release

Tags: python, vtk, joblib

I'm trying to parallelise processing of large datasets in VTK using its Python interface. For that, I want to use joblib since I have a (large) number of independent snapshots that I want to process and gather in a large numpy matrix, i.e. something like:

```py
import vtk
from vtk.numpy_interface import dataset_adapter as dsa
for i,snap in enumerate(snapshot_list):
   myVtkFilter.SetInputData(snap)
   result = myVtkFilter.GetOutput()
   output[i, :] = dsa.WrapDataObject(result).CellData['myArray']
```

However, I'm facing some issues:

1. If I use the default loky backend, Python complains about the output matrix not being writable (it's a very large dataset, a matrix like (100, 1000000, 3)). The fact that it needs to be serialised by loky would be a major overhead anyway;
2. If I want to use Python threads, the code runs alright, but it seems to me that VTK doesn't release the GIL for most of the time (only one core is used for the largest part of the time).
   I would expect that, like numpy, VTK calls should release the GIL (as per this release note http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/Announce-vtk-7-0-0-release-candidate-1-is-ready-td5735575.html), but it doesn't seem to be the case.

I'm using Python 3.7.3 with VTK 8.1.2. Any suggestions?

Comment: VTK does release the GIL, so I'm not sure what is the issue here.

Comment: https://vtk.org/pipermail/vtk-developers/2018-November/036543.html This post seems to be discussing something similar. Maybe it could be related to some VTK build flag? I just went with a standard pip3 install vtk, not sure if I have to compile VTK from scratch and add some option I'm not aware of.

Comment: Yes it is related, make sure to use  VTK_PYTHON_FULL_THREADSAFE.

Comment: FYI the last fix to this feature was here: https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/merge_requests/6064 and is present in VTK9, which you should use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was some issue with the GIL in VTK 8.2.0, they have been fixed here: https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview/-/issues/14169 and the fix is present in VTK 9.0.1.

Update to VTK 9.0.1 and use the  VTK_PYTHON_FULL_THREADSAFE=ON CMake option to fix your problem.

Comment: This solves the issue, thanks. A small suggestion: the VTK_PYTHON_FULL_THREADSAFE=ON is not present in the default CMakeLists.txt, I added it manually at the end of the file and then ran ccmake. For future releases, it might be good to have it in the list, even if set to OFF in the default case.

Comment: It is visible in cmake-gui or ccmake. Not sure what you are talking about.

Comment: If VTK is built on its own without Paraview the option is not present, it needs to be added manually.